# Set file path to download video file kept in another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, download

I'm using ASP(C#).NET
Need to access some video files that are kept in another server

say I'm using 111.222.33.33 & files are kept in 'repository' folder of  F: drive in  222.111.12.12

below is my code segment to pull file name & path into an asp gridview so that I can download these files by clicking on the download link.
I'm able to download the files when they are in the same IP address.
But I'm having trouble with the file path. Need some help with the UR. Thnx.

```
    String fileSearchPatern = "*.*";
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"\\222.111.12.12\F:\repository\"));

    if (gvSource == null)
    {
        gvSource = DisplayFilesInGridViewTwo();
    }
    DataRow gvRow;
    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles(fileSearchPatern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files)
    {
        gvRow = gvSource.NewRow();
        gvRow["Name"] = fileInfo.Name; 
        gvRow["FilePath"] = @"\\222.111.12.12\F:\repository\" + fileInfo.Name;  
        gvSource.Rows.Add(gvRow);

    }
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        this.GridView2.DataSource = gvSource;
        this.GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        this.GridView2.DataSource = null;
        this.GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly, but this might help, I can see clearly that on the network access you cannot use F: but have to use F$ instead, try to do the following steps please and tell me:

1- Check the network weather you can access the F drive by click on Windows + R, and write `@\\222.111.12.12\F$\repository`
2- If not, then check the network first connection, then weather this is shared or permission given to you or not..
3- If you want to store on this folder, you should give permission of Network Service to it, if only reading then no need, the exists permission should be enough then...

Comment: thnx for your suggesstions...I've just checked Windows+R and then writing @\\222.111.12.12\F$\repository. It doesn't work..so will check the config

Comment: Please remove the @ and try again, if it is the same then you need to solve Network issue before to go to the code part then...

Comment: yes...did that..it asks for username password..thnx